# How to set a textView with Autosized textType on a constraintLayout programmatically?

Tags: java, android-studio, textview

Hi all I'm a bloody beginner and need some help

I have to build a ContraintLAyout with 5 textviews in it on the Editor on Android Studio and now I need this ContraintLayout 42 times dynamically. So I searched a while for a solution and found something that could work. But the result is not the expected one.

```xml
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="MO"
                app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView4"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.34"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.34" />
```

how can I set these values on Java Code?

I have tried something like this

```java
GridLayout gridLayout = findViewById(R.id.kalenderfeldGL);
        ConstraintLayout tagesfeld = (ConstraintLayout) gridLayout.getChildAt(0);
        tagesfeld.setId(View.generateViewId());
        TextView tagname = new TextView(this);
        tagname.setId(View.generateViewId());
        //tagname.setHeight(0);
        //tagname.setWidth(0);
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams cltagesfele = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_CONSTRAINT_PERCENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_CONSTRAINT_PERCENT);
        tagname.setLayoutParams(cltagesfele);
        //tagname.setText("MO");
        TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(tagname, TextViewCompat.AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_UNIFORM);
        tagname.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        tagname.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        //tagname.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);



        //tagname.setText("MO");
        tagesfeld.addView(tagname);
        ConstraintSet cstagname = new ConstraintSet();
        //cstagname.clone(tagesfeld);
        cstagname.connect(tagname.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, tagesfeld.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);
        cstagname.connect(tagname.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, tagesfeld.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, 0);
        cstagname.constrainPercentHeight(tagname.getId(), 0.34F);
        cstagname.constrainPercentWidth(tagname.getId(), 0.34F);
        cstagname.applyTo(tagesfeld);
        tagname.setText("MO");
```

I want the "MO" letters in the left top side this works, but the letters are not side by side they are in vertical position and the O is cut on the underside.

Comment: Where are `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf` and `app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf` equivalents in your java code?

Comment: This is the problem. I dont know how to set it in java code. Can you give me an example how to do it?

Comment: First of all, you should have a reference to them, do you have their ids in your java code?

Comment: Oh sorry i didnt set the other 2 textviews yet i wanted to add one textview, and if that work ill continue with the other stuff i want

Comment: Why have you commented `cstagname.clone(tagesfeld);?
`

Comment: Because if i use it the textviews never appear

Comment: What is the exact problem that you are encountering?

Comment: Setting the to letters so they fill the textview automatically and central

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the max line limit of your textView to 1 in order to prevent "O" letter from going into the next line. Something like below:

```
tagname.setMaxLines(1);
```

UPDATE:

Try to reduce the minimum text size of `autoSizeTextType` by using this:

xml:

```
android:autoSizeMinTextSize="10sp"
```

Java:

```
tagname.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration(10, 100, 1, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP);
```

The  default value is `12sp` as noted in [android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview#granularity)
.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)